# Guidelines to create an ordered Quote-of-the-Day for x days feature in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an array of 40 different quotes:

```
let quotes = [
'Whatever you are, be a good one.',
'If not us, who? If not now, when?',
'If you dream it, you can do it.'
/*...*/
]
```

I would like to have 1 quote display for 1 day (24hrs), in order.

Once the program reaches the last (40th) quote, it should start over. So the program would take 40 full days to reach the end of the array.

I've nearly created a "random quote machine" with some tutorials, but creating an "ordered quote machine" has got me stumped.

Since JavaScript is a client side language, and it can't remember the days, how is this possible?

Comment: I understand that you have trouble with the coding, but this is not the place to ask those kinds of questions, You must provide us with a code so we can make it better, or you should ask programming related questions, not asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: @Aktar I have improved the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, you could use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with `j` (Day of the month without leading zeros):

```
$quotes = [
    'Don\'t cry because it\'s over, smile because it happened.',
    'So many books, so little time.',
    ...
];

echo $quotes[date('j')];
```

Pretty easy to convert to javascript, though your users will see all the quotes.